# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What are the minimum set of shoes required for hiking outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4246/what-are-the-minimum-set-of-shoes-required-for-hiking-outdoors)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Identifying named peaks from the summit of a north-american peak](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/identifying-named-peaks-from-the-summit-of-a-north-american-peak)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How can you tell if a rocky outcropping (lookout) is safe?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/is-the-lookout-safe)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What should I do for a dislocated shoulder?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4208/what-should-i-do-for-a-dislocated-shoulder)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What style of camelback hydrating systems exist out there?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4242/what-style-of-camelback-hydrating-systems-exist-out-there)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Where to carry a folding knife when hiking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/where-to-carry-a-folding-knife-when-hiking)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How do I find a less crowded trail in the southeast United States on the 4th of July?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/how-do-i-find-a-less-crowded-trail-in-the-southeast-on-the-4th)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Sustainable systems for carrying out human waste](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/sustainable-systems-for-carrying-out-human-waste)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Is it generally allowed to walk in German forests in the night?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/is-it-generally-allowed-to-walk-in-german-forests-in-the-night)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to harden feet for walking barefoot on harsh surfaces?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/how-to-harden-feet-for-walking-barefoot-on-harsh-surfaces)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)